# JDBC connection raises errors

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, oracle12c, oracle-apex-5

Hi everyone I have just migrated an APEX 4 application on a 10g database over to a new 12c database using with APEX 5. One of our developers is using a JDBC connection and receiving the following error:

> java.sql.SQLException: ORA-06550: line 1, column 16: PLS-00302: component 'IWAY_INSERT_IM_REQUEST' must be declared ORA-06550:

I was just wondering if 12c maybe behaves differently around these connections as the procedure being called is owned by the schema. The error is not making much sense and I can't seem to find a lot on this other than adding a synonym which has not helped us but I think I may just be overthinking this now and missing something simple. If anyone has any ideas it would be most helpful.

Comment: An ORA-06550 error means its a compilation error, so whatever procedure your calling wasn't compiled correctly.  It looks to me like IWAY_INSERT_IM_REQUEST may not have been loaded, or its definition got stepped on from an error on the prior line and your procedure calls it.  Your DBA should be able to see if there are compilation errors in the database, or you can use SQL Developer and look at the procedures to see which are invalid.

Comment: Sounds more like an anonymous PL/SQL block is being run from Java, and that block is getting the error - not that something in the DB has errors. Are you sure the DB user your developer is connecting as has execute permissions and a synonym for the package, if they aren't connecting as its owner; and is really connecting to the DB you think they are, and is seeing the version of the package you expect? (They might have a private version of the package which doesn't have that procedure, for instance).

Comment: Hi guys thanks for your responses. The database has no invalid objects so i think it is related to the java side. The proceedure runs when connecting in as toad but not from JDBC so I know we have the right connection details. Drivers have been updated... im trying to go through everything step by step.